# Calling a function in a renderer process when main window is closed in electron js

Tags: electron

I have a form(where users enter some inputs), in a renderer process and I have to store the values entered in localstorage when the MAIN WINDOW is closed. (Electron js app)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have a renderer process running where it displays a html form where users can enter values. Now , when I click the "X" close button in the Main window of my electron app , I should store the values entered in the form in local storage. How do I do this?.

Comment: have you tried to use [`'close'`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-close) event? (captured in main process, in callback notify renderer to do proper cleanup) or `window.onbeforeunload` in renderer as mentioned there.

Comment: I captured the close event by using 'close' as you suggested. Now I want a dialog box to show a message saying "Are you sure you want to quit" with a "yes" and a "no" button , and on clicking "yes" the app should close and on clicking "no" it should return to the window. How to do this using the dialog module?

Comment: Thank you , I implemented it using this code:
 var result=dialog.showMessageBox({
            message: "You should Click 'Next' to save your progress. Click 'Quit' to exit.",
            buttons: ["Quit","Continue"]
            });
            console.log(result);
            if(result==1)
            e.preventDefault();
            else 
            if(result==0)
            {//some process
            console.log("window closed"); });}
        });